# 'getDownloadURL' returns one less URL in a Promise

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I'm trying to upload several pictures to Firebase Storage and get their URLs to add these as a field in a gym's profile. However, with the code I came up with, always one URL is not returned. If I upload 3 pictures, 3 pictures appear in Storage but I only get 2 URLs. How do I fix that?

```
const promises = [];
const URLarray = [];

imageAsFile.forEach(img => {
            const uploadTask = storage.ref().child(`/photos/${doc.id}/${img.name}`).put(img);
            promises.push(uploadTask);
            uploadTask.then((uploadTaskSnapshot) => {
                return uploadTaskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
            }).then((pic) => {
                const addPics = db.collection("gyms").doc(doc.id)
                promises.push(addPics);
                addPics.update({gymPhoto: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(pic)});
                // URLarray.push(pic)
            })
    });

Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
    // console.log(URLarray)
    alert("Done");
})
```

Comment: `Promise.all(promises)` is always going to execute before any call to `promises.push(addPics)`.  Also, `doc()` does not return a promise, so you are pushing something that is not a promise into your promises array.  `update()` returns a promise, which you are currently ignoring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should work (untested):

```
const promises = [];

imageAsFile.forEach(img => {
    const uploadTask = storage.ref().child(`/photos/${doc.id}/${img.name}`).put(img);
    promises.push(uploadTask);
});

Promise.all(promises)
    .then(uploadTaskSnapshotsArray => {
        const promises = [];
        uploadTaskSnapshotsArray.forEach(uploadTaskSnapshot => {
            promises.push(uploadTaskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL());
        });

        return Promise.all(promises);
    })
    .then(urlsArray => {
        const docRef = db.collection("gyms").doc(doc.id);
        return docRef.update({ gymPhoto: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(...urlsArray) });
    })
```

[`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) returns a single promise: This promise is fulfilled with an Array containing all the resolved values in the Array passed as the argument.

So, if you call `Promise.all()` with the Array of `uploadTask`s, when the returned promise is fulfilled you will get an Array of [`uploadTaskSnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.UploadTaskSnapshot)s.

Then you need to use this Array to get an Array of URLs, again by using `Promise.all()`.

Then, when you get the Array of URLs, you need to update **only once** the document with id = doc.id. So here you don't need `Promise.all()`. What you need to do is to pass several values to the `FieldValue.arrayUnion()` method. For that you need to use the [Spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), as follows:

```
docRef.update({ gymPhoto: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(...urlsArray) });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot after hours of hair pulling your comment saved me from going crazy. one adjustment is in getDownloadUrl use getDownloadURL(uploadTaskSnap.ref).then((downloadUrl) => { return downloadUrl })